# Prove that portfolio is self financing?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance, stochastic-differential-equations

Let assume we have a portfolio with strategy described by $θ_t = \int_0^t S_udu$ (position in stock) and $ψ_t = -\int_0^t \frac{S_u^2}{B_u}du$ (position in bond). How to prove that this strategy is self financing?
The underlying stock process is $dS_t = μS_tdt + σS_tdW_t$ and underlying process in bond market is $dB_t = rB_tdt$.

From the definition, we have $$V = θ_tS_t + ψ_tB_t$$ $$dV = θ_tdS_t + ψ_tdB_t$$.

To prove this, we firstly set $$V = \int_0^t S_udu*S_t  -\int_0^t \frac{S_u^2}{B_u}du*B_t$$ and we need to prove that $dV$ of the above process will sattisfy equation $$dV = θ_tdS_t + ψ_tdB_t = (θ_tμS_t + ψ_trB_t)dt + θ_tS_tdW_t$$ that is $$dV = \left(μS_t\int_0^t S_udu - rB_t\int_0^t \frac{S_u^2}{B_u}du \right)dt + \left(S_t\int_0^t S_udu\right)dW_t$$
How to find $dV$ from $V$ described above?

Comment: There is no stochastic PDE in this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By differentiating $V$, we have
$$dV_t=\left(S_td\theta_t+\theta_tdS_t+d<S_t,\theta_t>\right)+\left(B_td\psi_t+\psi_tdB_t+d<B_t,\psi_t>\right)$$

We also have 
$$d\theta_t=S_tdt$$
$$d\psi_t=-\frac{S_t^2}{B_t}dt$$
and 
$$d<S_t,\theta_t>=0$$
$$d<B_t,\psi_t>=0$$
because $\theta$ and $\psi$ do not have a Brownian motion component.

Substituting these results to the first equation we have

$$dV_t=\left(S_t^2dt+\theta_tdS_t\right)+\left(-S_t^2dt+\psi_tdB_t\right)$$
Finally,
$$dV_t=\theta_tdS_t+\psi_tdB_t$$